# How to create a Macro for a specific purpose

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to create a Macro that will search for a project under a person's name, figure out what status it's in, paste it under the right heading, then increment a counter so that it will paste the next project in the right place.

The image shows the different headers and projects, the cells are referenced from the sheet RawData
[image]

Essentially, in the image there are 6 different headers and status's. Which are Assigned, Accepted, Work in Progress, On Hold, Completed, and Canceled. Each worksheet below is named under a different person, example, "WIPTX".

The code I have so far does not allow me to copy and paste into the different sections of the headers. All it does is loop through the Raw Data sheet and find the values from Range C1:C that have a value of Assigned and Thomas. Then copies and pastes into an entirely new section of worksheet called WIP. The Raw Data is connected to a sharepoint site that is updated daily. I am still new to VBA and still trying to find answers.

```
Sub Test()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim myRow As Long

myRow = 2
With Sheets("RawData")
    For Each Cell In .Range("C1:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value = "Assigned" And Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Thomas" Then
            .Rows(Cell.Row).copy Destination:=Sheets("WIP").Rows(myRow)
            myRow = myRow + 1
        End If
    Next Cell
End With

MsgBox "The code has completed successfully"

End Sub
```